# '/usr/bin/python3: Can't Open File 'test.py'' when executing .exe file using mono on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, python, raspberry-pi, mono

I'm currently trying to write a program in Visual Studio that builds successfully, and then when I transfer the solution over to my Raspberry Pi and use `Mono` to execute "TestPiPlate.exe" it gives me the error: "/usr/bin/python3: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" followed by a "done" statement that I inserted into my `c#` program.

This is for a automated Raspberry Pi project I'm doing, and I'm trying to test the relay plate using a written python script.

This is what I have currently for my Visual Studio code:

```
        iotlib.PythonScrpt full_test = new PythonScrpt("test.py");
        full_test.Run();
        Console.WriteLine("done");
```

The iotlib.PythonScrpt is set up correctly, so I don't understand why it cannot find the test.py file, as it is in the same directory as the .exe debugging file.

I expect the test to run and visually see the relays turn on via my script, but the error is preventing me from even testing the script.

Comment: Use the full path of your `.py` file (or you can get the full path of the executing CIL assembly (your `.exe`) and Path.Combine that to your script..)

Comment: @SushiHangover I added the full path of my `.py` file and it still tells me it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the user that runs *TestPiPlate.exe* have execution permissions on the *test.py* file.

Also, to debug this, try to run any bash command to see if that works using `Process.Start()`